# Object variable or with block variable not set with Range.Find()

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a value in a single column Range("BE") and the `Range.Find()` gets search value based on concatenated TextBox and ListBox value.

When run it says

> object variable or with block variable not set

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sear As String
Dim Rng2 As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORDER").Range("B2:B1000000")
  
Set Rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CONVERSION_DB").Range("G2:G1000000")

Me.Label22 = Me.TextBox1.value
Me.Label23 = Me.TextBox2.value
Me.Label24 = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
Me.Label25 = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)

'start here

Worksheets("CORRUGATE_DB").Activate
Dim MyCount As Long
MyCount = Application.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CORRUGATE_DB").Range("BE2:BE1000000"), TextBox1.value & Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0))
Me.TextBox3.value = MyCount
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Iteration

Set Rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CORRUGATE_DB").Range("BE2:BE1000000")
Worksheets("CORRUGATE_DB").Activate
Set ws = ActiveSheet
 
sear = CStr(Me.TextBox1.value & Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)) ' <=== ERROR SHOWS AFTER HERE
   
ws.Range("BE2").Activate
Rng2.Find(What:=sear, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
  xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
  , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Me.TextBox4.value = Me.TextBox4.value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, -30).value
```

Comment: That means the find didn't work. You should always test for that before trying to use the result cell.

Comment: Where is your code placed, and where is TextBox and ListBox. Me depends on them.

Comment: my TextBox and ListBox found in the same userform with this code itself ...... the "Me.textBox" part is not the problem

Comment: @ace99 if not any row selected listindex=-1, but List property arguments start from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern for using `Find()` generally looks like this:

```
Dim f As Range
'...
'...
Set f = Rng2.Find(What:=sear, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


If Not f Is Nothing Then
    'do something with f
    Me.TextBox4.value = Me.TextBox4.value + f.Offset(0, -30).value
Else
    'no match was found
End If
```

You should always be testing whether a match was made before trying to access the range returned from `Find`.